# Acknowledgement section

Tags: thesis, writing, acknowledgement

I am tempted to thank the cast of a television show in my acknowledgement section of my thesis. Has anyone else done this?...the show was literally the only thing I would watch while writing...and I really don't have a lot of other people to thank.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! Could you clarify if your question actually is 'has anyone else done this', or 'is this acceptable' etc? In general, acknowledgement section is where you have a pretty free hand, I don't foresee objections to what you are proposing.

Comment: I am really sorry you have had that experience. Occasionally it happens. Keep in mind (in your thoughts, not on paper ;-)) that even bad experiences can be something to be grateful for because it teaches you sharply the person you not want to (become to) be. Don’t loose you positive attitude. And be the supervisor (team leader / boss) you wanted to have, when you are in that position later in life.

Answer (score 4):

Acknowledgement section is actually a place where a researcher specifies the contributions of other people/organizations or even the TV show like in your case, to the research. However, it mostly transformed into one/two page to thank first your advisor/coadvisor than colleagues than your friends than family and if there is, your significant other.

I really don't understand why it evolved to that but still, you can really write whatever you want there.

"I want to acknowledge "" TV show as their performance greatly helped me to write and tidy up my thesis". I would write like this.